# in SCDF(Spring Cloud Data Flow), how can i deploy application(stream or task) as statefulset? not deployment

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-kubernetes

in SCDF(Spring Cloud Data Flow), how can i deploy application(stream or task) as statefulset? not deployment

I could find some properties related to statefulset (ex: statefulsetInitcontainer, volumeClaimTemplate,...)
but I couldn't find any property that makes SCDF deploy app as statefulset.

Is there any method that I want??

Answer (score 0):

At the moment we use Spring Cloud Deployer for Kubernetes and only create deployments. What are your requirements and thinking for using Stateful sets?